# ColdFusion spreadsheet error, invalid date or time string

Tags: date, coldfusion, spreadsheet, export-to-excel, coldfusion-10

I am trying to export a query to an Excel document.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<cfscript> 
    //Use an absolute path for the files. ---> 
    theDir=GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()); 
    theFile=theDir & "invoicesDue.xls"; 
    //Create an empty ColdFusion spreadsheet object. ---> 
    theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("invoicesData"); 
    //Populate the object with a query. ---> 
    SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,invoicesDue);  
</cfscript>

<!--- Write the sheet to a file ---> 
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" name="theSheet" sheetname="invoicesDue" overwrite=true>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
'' is an invalid date or time string. 

121: SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,invoicesDue);
```

The thing is, I have dumped out my query and there are no quotation marks anywhere to be seen and all the date/time cells are either populated with a datetime such as "2011-03-31 00:00:00.0" or an empty string.

I wondered if anyone else has encountered this error before as I can't see the cause for it.

Comment: I believe the error message is showing you the value determined to be invalid.  In this case '' or empty string.  It is not suggesting that there are quotes in the value.  So apparently the `SpreadsheetAddRows` function does not like empty values for date fields when creating the spreadsheet.  That's my guess anyway.  Is it possible to eliminate rows with empty date fields from your query or do you still need those in the spreadsheet?  In which case you will probably need some way to set a default date value for those empty dates.

Comment: Why not just feed the query straight to cfspreadsheet instead of passing it a spreadsheet object? Should do all the work for you then. <cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" query="invoicesDue" sheetname="invoicesDue" overwrite=true>

Comment: Feeding the query on its own didn't do it either. Did some testing and @Miguel-F was right, cfspreadsheet doesn't like empty values for date fields. In the end I used `CAST(emptyDate as varchar)` which seems to be a fix. Thanks.

Comment: @Alias, you may want to add your solution as an answer so that it's more visible to others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cfspreadsheet doesn't like empty values for date fields. In the end I used:

```
CAST(emptyDate as varchar)
```

Which seems to be a fix.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I use Ben Nadel's [queryToCSV() function](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1239-Updated-Converting-A-ColdFusion-Query-To-CSV-Using-QueryToCSV-.htm) and bypass the "quirkiness" of `cfspreadsheet`. When all I need is a single page csv / xls file, it works like a charm.

Comment: Hi Dan, I am pretty sure that the delimiter is an argument for that function.